# How to make a mysql database in windows

Tags: mysql, database

Currently I'm working on access database(.mdb) but I wanted to transfer to mysql database. Currently I'm working on windows 7 machine and installed mysql from http://www.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ .
I opened Mysql workbench and created a new EER MODAL ?? as shown in this screenshot[image] . But I still couldn't figure out which one is the database and how to use it. Heres another screenshot of the table modal , and how to save the database to a location when I want.
[image]
PS: I'm totally new to mysql and I use access databases and I still don't know if I'm in the right way. Please suggest me if not. thanks

Comment: for simplified use you can use phpmyadmin for performing mysql queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the MySQL server running on your local machine. To access it, you would connect to localhost:3306 (I think you have your port set to 3306 from the screenshot I see).

Your second screenshot is the database you are connected to in SQL workbench and what tables it contains. If you give some information on how you are going to be using the DB, I can give you some more information to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm basically using it to store date, time and currency. I'm programming in vb.net and using simple sql's. Isn't it possible to simply copy the database to some other places?

Comment: You can't just copy and paste an Access DB into mysql. You would need to run a tool to import the data. Within your VB code, you will make a connection to the database and query it like any other SQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a new ERR Model. Just make a new connection and New server instance & you are done. If possible do try to install Wamp too.

Comment: how do I created a mysql database then?

Comment: This might help you http://users.drew.edu/bburd/rubyonrails/CreatingAdatabaseWithMySQLworkbench.pdf